# itext Sharp and PDF form stamping with parentheses

Tags: itext, acrobat, pdfstamper

My pdf doesnt show the negative numbers correctly i've set up a pdf form with acrobat which contains textfeild formated as numbers.

it doesnt display the negative numbers correctly when filled via itext sharp using the stamper

unless both Show Parnetheses and use red text are ticked

i just need parentheses but not red numbers for negative number styles  has anyone else come accross this error?

Answer (score 1):

couldnt find an answer so have manualy coded the parentheses

```
Function fixnegatives(astring As String) As String
    If IsNumeric(astring) Then
        Dim aint As Integer = CInt(astring)
        astring = String.Format("{0:#,###,###}", aint)
        If (aint < 0) Then
            Dim bstring As New StringBuilder(astring)
            bstring.Replace("-", "(")
            bstring.Append(")")
            astring = bstring.ToString()
        End If
    End If
    Return astring
End Function
```